# Is double assignment valid in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, c, variable-assignment

Is the following line in objective-c compiles like in C?

```
a=b=1;
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile it?

Comment: I wanted to know it's the same behaviour to avoid an unexpected bug

Comment: As I said, I wanted to know the expected behaviour, not if it will compile

Comment: @Tomer The point of this site is not answering questions which you can google or learn easily by some other ways. We like simple question but not the ones where no prior effort has been involved. Please, read the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works the same as in C.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C is a superset of C, so everything that works in C works in Objective-C.